# Unable to uninstall Paragon HFS+ For Windows

Tags: windows-10, malware, uninstall, malware-removal

I wanted to create a bootable usb key of MacOS Sierra so I needed to be able to read HFS partition on my Windows 10 computer.

After a quick research I found this software: [HFS4Win](https://www.paragon-software.com/fr/home/hfs-windows/)

But this software is such a pain to uninstall, the built-in uninstaller isn't working, I'm still seeing it into my program list.

The only help I found online is just some websites trying to make you install their "magic tool to repair and uninstall malware" which is as bad as the Paragon's one.

Does somebody know how can I completely remove this software ? I tried to do a system recovery from a few hour before the installation but an error occured during the process so the system still the same and the Paragon's software still here.

**EDIT**

As you asked, there is a service running called `apmwinsrv`. I tried to uninstall the application from the Programs and Features panel, also with CCleaner running as administrator. I had to stop the service before being able to run the uninstaller but the result is the same, the Paragon HFS+ for Windows entry still in my programs list.
When I try to remove it, I have an admin popup asking for a program to be elevated: `C:\WINDOWS\Installer\ac2a1a.msi`

So when I go to this executable I can try to manually uninstall it with admins rights but I have the same result as before.

Finally, there is a screenshot of the content of the install :

[image: paragon]

As you can see there is a reg modifier so I'm afraid that my register was modify. and if I look on all subdirectories, there is nothing talking about an uninstaller.exe

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information then simply telling us the uninstaller isn't working.

Comment: Try manually removing it from Program Files or AppData. We need more information than just the fact that its not uninstalling. Are you running the uninstaller as admin? does it have a service running in the background? etc..

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Processes can be stopped, and files, folders, and registry entries can be deleted. What we cannot tell you is whether this application stores ALL of its content in obvious locations or not. You will have to learn that from the software developers and support staff. Have you contacted them for support removing the software? You appear to have assumed the software was malicious and began treating it as such, when there is little indication that is actually the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted paragon and they gave me this solution (that worked on my paragon so, GOOD LUCK!)

1. Launch `HFSCleaner-2.exe` as Admin, let it perform its task, then reboot PC when prompted.

   - *`HFSCleaner-2.exe` received from Paragon Support*
2. Delete these files from `C:\Windows\system32\drivers`:

   - `apmwin`, `apmwinsrv`, `csvol`, `gpt_loader`, `mounthlp`, `hfsplus`, `hfsplusrec`
3. Install latest [HFS4Win](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/)