# Uninstall Paragon HFS+ .msi

Tags: windows-10, malware, uninstall, malware-removal, paragon

I am unable to remove Paragon HFS+ from my Windows 10 computer. The program is still listed after uninstalling using Add or Remove Programs. Running the command

```
msiexec /x Paragon-607-PEU_WinInstallSN-11.3.221.msi
```

I get this error message:

[image: .msi removal error message]

although the .msi file does exist.

I have also followed the steps in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DjIKwHw-mk), and tried geek uninstaller with no results. There are no Paragon related files in the registry, the program is not running in the task manager, I can't see it in the Start menu or search for it, but it's *still* listed in Apps and Features and won't uninstall. I am unable to install a new version or any other similar software, as this old version must be uninstalled first.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1356968/unable-to-uninstall-paragon-hfs-for-windows) from 2018 provides an answer but requires a "cleaner" file from Paragon that is **not publicly available**. Paragon will not provide information through their customer service portal, email or over their phone line and there is no uninstall program available through paragon's website.

The software is 100% legitimate and purchased through Paragon.

Does Windows have any methods to completely remove software? It seems strange that users are not given that option.

Comment: "suspect it's become scamware" What would draw you to that conclusion? Paragon has always been a reputable company. Where did you download the app from, directly from Paragon, or from some random scamware site? The linked question states that the uninstaller was obtained directly from Paragon Support. Try contacting them for the same file.

Comment: There is no such product as "Paragon HFS+ 2021". If the advice in the question from 2018 didn't work, you have probably downloaded a virus. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Comment: Paragon usually takes 24 - 48hrs to respond via email, however your license issue is an either/or: either you installed it previously and that activation needs to be de-activated via your account on Paragon's site or you bought the license before they switched to a better licensing system that doesn't lock you out after three license de-activations - you can try creating an account on their new licensing [portal](https://uc.paragon-software.com), else you'll need to wait for them to respond with a new license key in a day or two

Answer (score 0):

If you have paid for software and need help with it then the correct answer is ["Contact Paragon support"](https://www.paragon-software.com/support/). It's important to tell support about problems with their software so they can fix it. Once they fix it for you they can fix it for everyone with a software update.

Outside of the regular support channel the answer to uninstalling any software that gets stuck is to use a tool like [the Geek Unintsaller](https://geekuninstaller.com/). The Geek will remove all files left behind and all registry items. After that it can forcibly remove the entry from your Add\Remove program list. I use it every time I can't uninstall a program and I've never seen it fail.

Finally, if you want to remove things manually just uninstall the drivers, delete the files and remove the entry from the registry.

Anything that shows up under "Add or Remove Programs" is found at this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

You can read more about this directly from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-manually-remove-programs-from-the-add-remove-programs-list-49494159-d215-07b2-e4c7-050457b38352).

Comment: After more than 10 days I had to call corporate sales to get a response from support, and their solution hasn't worked. Neither did the Geek Uninstaller.

Comment: @Zeesy, did you run "Force removal" from the Geek? It can't really fail because it deletes everything itself.

Comment: I did try with the Pro verison trial, but am required to pay in USD to use the Force Remove feature. Because of the bootcamp issue, I am unable to try other the other HFS programs as the trials ran out before I could use them. And I'm concerned that even if I pay for third party software, reinstalling HFS+ may cause additional issues. You can see how I feel like I'm being held hostage here. I'm also baffled as to why there is no command-line option to remove programs from Windows.

Comment: Geek is free. I've never even seen the PRO version. If the uninstaller is broken then running it from the command line can't help you. All geek does is manually delete all the files and associated registry keys. That's all an uninstaller does too. You could do it yourself if you wanted. I added the registry key where all your programs are listed. If you remove it from there then it will appear to be uninstalled so be sure to remove the files first.

Comment: Geek works great as long as you only use the free version. On the official Geek downloads page there are two options - Free and Pro. Pro costs $24.95 and offers a free trial, but will only force uninstall after it is paid for. The free version force uninstalls without needing to pay. For some reason, the Paragon registry keys are not all obviously related to Paragon, so removing all the files and registry keys manually isn't enough without taking a chance on deleting potentially unrelated keys.