# "MacDrive Isn't Working / Boot Camp is Active"

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, boot-camp

I have installed the most recent version of MacDrive to copy files from my Windows 10 PC to a Mac formatted HD. I have been getting the error message "MacDrive Isn't Working / Boot Camp is Active", and as recommended by the docs have tried repairing/restarting/uninstalling/restarting several times. I had previously installed Paragon HFS+, but have been unable to do a complete uninstall (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1638192/uninstall-paragon-hfs-software-in-2021?noredirect=1#comment2502871_1638192)). This [Reddit post from 2016](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/5atxcv/i_accidentally_installed_both_macdrive_and/) suggests that there may be a conflict preventing MacDrive from running.

Has anyone had any experience with this error in MacDrive? The official documentation has not been helpful.

Comment: We need more info. What version of MacDrive, what format is the Mac disk? Wouldn't it have been more sensible to have ensured removal of the conflicting Paragon driver first?

Comment: It's not possible to remove the conflicting Paragon driver without Paragon support, and Paragon support doesn't respond to uninstall requests.